# PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class

Tags: postgresql, constraint, installation, exclusion-constraint, gist-index

In PostgreSQL 9.2.3 I am trying to create this simplified table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    user_id INTEGER,
    startend TSTZRANGE,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (user_id WITH =, startend WITH &&)
);
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"
> HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define
>        a default operator class for the data type.
> ```

The [PostgreSQL docs use this example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/rangetypes.html) which does not work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE room_reservation (
    room text,
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (room WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

Same error message.

[And this one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/btree-gist.html), which does not work for me either:

```
CREATE TABLE zoo (
    cage   INTEGER,
    animal TEXT,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (cage WITH =, animal WITH <>)
);
```

Same error message.

I am able to create this without any problem:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    user_id INTEGER,
    startend TSTZRANGE,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (startend WITH &&)
);
```

and this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    user_id INTEGER,
    startend TSTZRANGE,
    EXCLUDE USING btree (user_id WITH =)
);
```

I've spent quite a bit of time searching for hints about figuring out how to make this work, or figuring out why it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Follow-up question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37391/postgresql-create-extension-file-not-found-error-on-mac-os

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Install the additional module [**`btree_gist`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) as is mentioned in the manual [at the location you linked to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT):

> You can use the `btree_gist` extension to define exclusion constraints
> on plain scalar data types, which can then be combined with range
> exclusions for maximum flexibility. For example, after `btree_gist` is
> installed, the following constraint will reject overlapping ranges
> only if the meeting room numbers are equal:

In modern PostgreSQL you only need to run (once per database):

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

You need to have the "contrib" package installed in your OS first. Details depend on your OS and the software repository used. For the Debian family it's typically `postgresql-contrib-13` (for Postgres 13). Or just `postgresql-contrib` for the Red Hat family. Consider this related answer on SO:

- [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101055/939860)

Comment: [link to postgres mailing list thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130322205714.GA27152%40llserver.lakeliving.com) with answer

Answer (score 5):

if someone can't or doesn't want to use this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

As it was in my case, because Django 1.11 ORM does not support this index and I didn't want to write SQL outside Django. I used something similar to:

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (
    int4range(userid, userid, '[]') WITH =,
    startend WITH && 
)
```

'[]' is used to make sure both bounds are inclusive. Tested with Postgres 9.6 and 10.5.