# PostgreSQL CREATE EXTENSION file not found error on Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, installation, mac-os-x, postgresql-extensions

On PostgreSQL 9.2.3 when trying this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: could not open extension control file "/opt/local/share/postgresql92/extension/btree_gist.control": No such file or directory

Running `SELECT pg_available_extensions();` shows that indeed is not available.

Comment: Googling shows that it's supplied as a .sql file that you run.

Comment: Probably, depending on the way you have installed Postgres, there's an extra ["contrib"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) package you need to install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the needed contrib files are not installed. This was actually the case for several contrib modules.

I found help with the solution to this here:
https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/display/ITDOC/Get+PostgreSQL+contrib+modules+on+Mac+OS+X

```
$ su
# port build postgresql92
# cd `port work postgresql92`/postgresql-<version>/contrib
# for d in *; do test -d $d && ( echo $d; cd $d; make all && make install; cd .. ); done
```

I suspect reinstalling everything would work too, but this highlights the actual problem.

Comment: I recently installed 9.3 (sudo port install postgresql93-server) and uninstalled 9.2 (sudo port uninstall <all related ports>). Today, upon doing a restore I found that CREATE EXTENSION didn't work for this same reason. Executing the above four lines for the appropriate version fixed the problem.