# Unique constraint to enforce max one null per item

Tags: postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint, exclusion-constraint

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3. Suppose we are manufacturing some items of certain types, at any moment we are producing at most one item of a certain type. The following table captures our history of manufactured items, there may be rows where `manufactured_until` is `null` - those are the items produced currently.

```
create table item
(
  id int,
  type_id int,
  manufactured_from timestamp,
  manufactured_until timestamp
)
```

Sample data:

```
1  | 101  | 1.1.2000    | 31.12.2012
2  | 102  | 1.4.2003    | 1.1.2010
3  | 101  | 1.1.2013    | 
4  | 102  | 2.1.2010    | 4.5.2014
5  | 102  | 5.5.2014    |
```

The following logic should hold: for each item type, there should be at most one item being produced at the moment (`manufactured IS NULL`). In the example, I should not be able to add the record `(6, 101, 27.8.2014, NULL)`.

I'd like to write a `UNIQUE` constraint that will guard this. Is it possible? For bonus points, is there a reasonably complex way to guard that the intervals do not overlap for one item type?

Comment: I reopened the question, since you have sneaked in a second question (we prefer ***one*** question per question). This may be of help for the main question (unique and NULL): [Multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values). And this for the 2nd one (exclusion constraint): [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A partial unique index should do this:

```
create unique index max_one_null 
   on item (type_id) 
where manufactured_until is null;
```

> *For bonus points, is there a reasonably complex way to guard that the intervals do not overlap for one item type*

Look into range types and exclusion constraints. They were specifically designed for this problem.

Something like this (untested):

```
create table item
(
  id int,
  type_id int,
  manufactured_during tsrange
);
```

The inserts will look a bit different as there is only a single column now:

```
insert into item 
  (id, type_id, manufactured_during)
values 
  (1, 101, '[2000-01-01,2012-12-31]'),
  (1, 101, '[2013-01-01,)');
```

`[2000-01-01,2012-12-31]` defines a closed interval that includes both dates. `[2013-01-01,)` defines an open interval without an end (maps to `manufactured_until is null` with your current table design)

Then add an exclusion constraint to guard the range:

```
alter table item
  add constraint check_manufactured_range
  exclude using gist (type_id with =, manufactured_during with &&);
```

You don't need a unique index any more because the constraint will make sure that nothing will overlap.

More information in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html

If you search the internet for "Postgres exclusion constraints" you will find several presentations and blog posts regarding this topic.

P.S.: it seems that you actually want a `daterange` (instead of a "timestamp range") because you probably don't want to include the time of day with the intervals that define when something was manufactured.

Comment: The exclude constraint requires that you install the extension `btree_gist` for the included `integer`. Details: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/postgresql-exclude-using-error-data-type-integer-has-no-default-operator-class/37373#37373