# Optimizing a "categorized" search table using trigrams

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-9.6, gist-index, postgresql-performance

I've been reading through [this excellent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103823/150338) to understand how pg_trgm works a bit, but I'm still unclear on the most efficient way of solving this query (efficient in terms of speed of search):

I have a table `search` that I run trigram searches on that looks like this:

```
Column      |  Type   | Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------
id          | bpchar  | collate C
user_id     | integer |
type        | text    |
search_on   | text    | collate C
data        | json    |
Indexes:
 "index_search_id" UNIQUE, btree (id)
 "index_search_search_on" gist (search_on gist_trgm_ops)
 "index_search_type" btree (type)
 "index_search_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

In this scenario, `user_id` is `NULLable` and `type` is *also* `NULLable`. The queries I'd run amount to these possibilities:

1. Search for rows `(WHERE user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL) AND search_on % 'mystring'`
2. Search for rows `(WHERE user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL) AND type='my-type' AND search_on % 'mystring'`

In plain words, I want all rows that have *my* user_id or NULL user_id, optionally are categorized by `type`, and match the term being passed in.

Right now I just have individual indexes on the 3 columns (as shown above) that can change based on the query. I understand however that a single index is generally more efficient.

Is it possible to use a single index that does trigram searches, but also exact match on `user_id` and `type` where they can optionally be `NULL`.

Comment: I assume you mean `WHERE` **`(`** `user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL` **`)`** `AND search_on % 'mystring'`? You need parentheses to keep `AND` binding before `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a single index that does trigram searches, but also exact match on `user_id` and `type` where they can optionally be NULL.

Yes, NULL is included in indexes. And you can search for it like for any other value.

Yes, you can have a multicolumn trigram GiST index. But GiST indexes typically don't make sense for the data type `integer`. Btree indexes are better in every respect - except for your case of a multicolumn index. So Postgres does not install the required operator class by default. You need to install the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) first, once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;  -- only if not installed, yet
```

Then you can create your multicolumn index:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON search USING gist (user_id, type, search_on gist_trgm_ops);
```

Related (with detailed instructions):

- [PostgreSQL EXCLUDE USING error: Data type integer has no default operator class](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37351/postgresql-exclude-using-error-data-type-integer-has-no-default-operator-class/37373#37373)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

And get [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) in your `WHERE` clause right:

```
WHERE (user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL)  -- parentheses!
AND    search_on % 'mystring'
```

Or:

```
WHERE (user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL)
AND   (type = 'my-type' OR type IS NULL)
AND    search_on % 'mystring'
```

Depending on data distribution, cardinalities, selectivity of predicates, cost settings etc. Postgres may still prefer an index on one (or two) column(s) (occasionally).

Comment: While NULL values are supported in indexes in general, the way `btree_gist` in particular supports them is rather disgraceful.  He is quite unlikely to find the multi-column gist index to outperform the three independent indexes, unless he recodes his data so that it uses a dummy non-NULL value rather than NULL.

Comment: Actually it appears to the entire GiST framework, not just `btree_gist`, which can't cope gracefully with NULLs.

Comment: @jjanes: That's bad news. I didn't test performance with NULL values in particular. Would you happen to have a link to more info on this?

Comment: @brad: Since you have a use case at hand: Could you test performance with the suggested index with `user_id = 123` and `user_id IS NULL`?

Comment: Just my own experimentation.  There is this somewhat cryptic comment in the code "On non-leaf page we can't conclude that child hasn't NULL values because of assumption in GiST: union (VAL, NULL) is VAL."  It seems like that assumption should be explained elsewhere as well in more depth, but I can't find it.

Comment: ya I'm going to benchmark this when I have a chance. I'll post my findings when I do

Comment: I added my results below. Looks like the gist with NULLs worked fine, but as stated, the amount of NULL values is pretty low (on my current dataset)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay on this one. I'm not sure if protocol dictates that I answer my own question to post these details, but comments (to Erwin's answer) don't provide enough space.

So I was noticing pretty poor performance using the above individual indexes when I'd run queries. I have 2 main uses cases:

1. Query for all things in the 'public sphere' or my own: `(user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL) AND search_on % 'my_string'`
2. Query for all things by type, in the 'public sphere' or my own `(user_id = 123 OR user_id IS NULL) AND type='my-type' AND search_on % 'mystring'`

I forgot to mention that `type IS NOT NULL` in all of this, so there's never a case where I want to fetch NULL typed rows, only NULL user_id rows.

Using the separate indexes from the original post, I'd see queries taking anywhere from 1s to 10+s. It *seemed* as if "warming up" and running a few queries would bring the time down, but even 1 second is insufficient for a typeahead without negatively affecting the UX.

Playing with Erwin's suggestions, I added first:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_typed_search ON search USING gist (user_id, type, search_on gist_trgm_ops);
```

And ran both typed and non-typed queries. The typed queries were insanely fast (~ 50 ms) and the non-typed were still pretty slow, but definitely faster than the original posting with separate indexes (~ 400 ms)

Then I added:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_search ON search USING gist (user_id, search_on gist_trgm_ops);
```

and ran both typed and non-typed queries. As expected, typed queries weren't affected, they used the other index, but non-typed queries actually got worse (~ 1000+ ms). Dropping that index brought them back down to (~ 400ms)

So I wasn't sure if it was the presence of two potentially competing indexes to choose from that caused performance issues. Since I'm absolutely satisfied with the typed indexing (~ 50ms is roughly the speed I was hoping for) I decided to focus just on the untyped queries.

With no indexes, the baseline query using a sequence scan runs in about 8s (roughly 700,000 total rows)

With the individual btree index on `user_id` plus the gist_trgm on `search_on`, the performance is in the 400ms range. Interestingly it never uses the user_id index, because by the time it index scans on the search term, there's probably only a few rows to filter out from *other* user_ids (given my current data). This could likely change over time with more user data though, so I think the user_id index still makes sense even though its unused in this case.

With the combined gist (user_id, search_on) index, I get performance roughly similar to the 2 separate indexes (~ 400ms)

I should mention that the shape of the data is such that there would be 100's of records owned by each user_id, but 100's of 1000's (a majority) of records in the 'public sphere' (user_id IS NULL).

Given that data shape, it seems best to simply optimize for the search term and type themselves, as the user_id filtering at the end of the query is cheap.

Since a specific non-typed index doesn't actually yield any performance benefit, it seems the best option is to stick with a single gist index on the `type` and `search_on` columns only:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_typed_global_search ON searchables USING gist (type, search_on gist_trgm_ops);
```

I don't have enough users currently to test the user_id filtering, but my guess is that as we grow our user base, an index on user_id would yield fruit.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. No big surprises, but interesting & useful in any case.